# SQL Server: conditional aggregation

Tags: sql-server

I have this table:

[image]

What I want to do is aggregate these so each instructor has one line, so I used this SQL:

```
Select 
    TermCode, SubjectCode, course, QuestionNbr, InstructorName,    
    Sum(TotalStudents) as TotalStudents, Avg(Mean) as Mean, 
    StDev(StdDev) as StdDev
From 
    @MyTable
Group By 
    TermCode, SubjectCode, course, QuestionNbr, InstructorName
```

And I get this:

[image]

The problem is that any instructor with just one entry will have a null StdDev, which is to be expected.  What I want is in those cases to use the StdDev value from the original table, so I would get this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you just put stddev together like that?
At least the avg is wrong: What is the average of one class with 1 student getting 5 and another class with 99 students getting 1? Your formula gives 3, I'd say 1.04. 
Toget the real stddev, you need access to the original grades of all students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use COALESCE with an aggregate function that won't return NULL - such as Max:

```
COALESCE(StDev(StdDev),Max(StdDev)) as StdDev
```

Comment: I'd say this is the right answer to the wrong question ;-)

Comment: Ye gods.  I tried the Coalesce before I wrote this, but I used Coalesce(StDev(StdDev), StdDev)) instead.